Next JS S3 Upload Error using s3-presigned-post
I am working with Nextjs 14.2.5 trying to upload a file to aws S3 using createPresignedPost but I got cors error stats 400
, working on the local environment and also using Cloudfront with S3 bucket
Here is my code
page.tsx
'use client'
import { useState } from 'react'
export default function Page() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null)
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false)
  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (!file) {
      alert('Please select a file to upload.')
      return
    }
    setUploading(true)
    const response = await fetch(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL + '/api/test/upload',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ filename: file.name, contentType: file.type }),
      }
    )
    if (response.ok) {
      const { url, fields } = await response.json()
      const formData = new FormData()
      Object.entries(fields).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        formData.append(key, value as string)
      })
      formData.append('file', file)
      const uploadResponse = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      })
      if (uploadResponse.ok) {
        alert('Upload successful!')
      } else {
        console.error('S3 Upload Error:', uploadResponse)
        alert('Upload failed.')
      }
    } else {
      alert('Failed to get pre-signed URL.')
    }
    setUploading(false)
  }
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Upload a File to S3</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          id="file"
          type="file"
          onChange={(e) => {
            const files = e.target.files
            if (files) {
              setFile(files[0])
            }
          }}
          accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
        />
        <button type="submit" disabled={uploading}>
          Upload
        </button>
      </form>
    </main>
  )
}

api route.tsx
import { createPresignedPost } from '@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post'
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const { filename, contentType } = await request.json()
  try {
    const client = new S3Client({  region: process.env.AWS_REGION!,
        credentials: {
          accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID!,
          secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY!,
        }, })
    const { url, fields } = await createPresignedPost(client, {
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME!,
      Key: uuidv4(),
      Conditions: [
        ['content-length-range', 0, 10485760], // up to 10 MB
        ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', contentType],
      ],
      Fields: {
        acl: 'public-read',
        'Content-Type': contentType,
      },
      Expires: 600, // Seconds before the presigned post expires. 3600 by default.
    })
    return Response.json({ url, fields })
  } catch (error:any) {
    return Response.json({ error: error.message })
  }
}

console error on API request

.env.local
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=m/xxxxxxxx
AWS_REGION=us-east-2
AWS_BUCKET_NAME=BUCKETNAME
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000

AWS S3 Bucket Policy
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::XXXXXXXXX:distribution/XXXXXXXXX"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Bucket CORS Configuration
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]

IAM User Plocy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:GetObjectAttributes",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Please help me with this
Thanks in advance
